# What is meant by "Des êtres et des génies"?

Tags: vocabulaire

I'm searching course options for my Fall semester in CEGEP, and one of the courses offered is called "Des êtres et des génies." My problem is that I'm having some trouble understanding what the course is actually about. Here is its description:

> Qu’est-ce qui détermine nos actes? De quoi dépend notre succès? Quel impact les innovations technologiques ont-elles sur notre vie? Ce sont des questions auxquelles ce cours tentera de répondre en les examinant sous l’angle de la psychologie sociale. Quatre thèmes y seront étudiés à travers des documents scientifiques écrits et multimédias récents. Plus spécifiquement, on parlera d’actes individuels et collectifs, d’aliénation sociale, ainsi que de certaines innovations techniques et de leurs conséquences sur l’insertion sociale et la réussite. À la fois vivant et rigoureux, ce cours permettra aux étudiants de mieux comprendre la complexité de l’être humain, ses faiblesses, mais aussi son génie.

From what I read, it seems like it studies the social effects of science, the *sociology* of science, from passages like "Qu’est-ce qui détermine nos actes," "examinant sous l’angle de la psychologie sociale," and "certaines innovations techniques et de leurs conséquences sur l’insertion sociale," which would make sense, since they relate your French courses to your program at CEGEP.

I'm also somewhat confused by the title. As I understand, "être" is a verb, but the title seems to use "être" as a noun, with "des êtres."

So what is meant by "Des êtres et des génies", and what is the main idea of the course?

Comment: As a note, I'm not entirely sure what tags this question fits under, so I encourage anyone who does to edit the tags.

Comment: [Être (see the second tab)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/%C3%AAtre) is also a noun: being. I won't try to answer what is the course about.

Comment: That's still helpful. Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cegep course descriptions have a way to be vague, as do university's. That is probably because they have a guideline to follow, but each teacher or professor will go about it a different way, so the description snippets can't be too precise.

That being said, that class will explore social psychology. Course names are sometimes embellished for various reasons. Sometimes it's to try to attract more people (because "Des êtres et des génies" sounds cooler than "Psychologie sociale"), or because there's a weird administration thing and the same course is given under two different codes and they therefore need two different titles (a professor teaching a class titled "Le Québec de 1960 à nos jours" confirmed that he was teaching the exact same thing in another class titled "Histoire du Québec contemporain"), or perhaps for another obscure reason.

As you said "être" can also be a noun, and it's very much equal to "being" which is also a verb and a noun, and means the exact same thing in French and English as verb and as noun. "Génies" in this case would not mean "genies" as the magical being, but would rather mean "geniuses". It would seem that in that course, you would study the psychology behind actions, individual and collective, as well as their consequences on society. It would seem that the course title is derived from trying to teach why some men stay as "normal beings" while others are elevated to "geniuses".

Comment: Intéressant, pour vous ce n'est pas inné.

Answer (score 2):

On peut risquer une interprétation des concepts sous-tendus :

- *Des êtres* : les femmes et les hommes, ancêtres et descendance, tout ce qui concerne les gens : la vie et sa manifestation au quotidien.
- *Des génies* : les lois abstraites qui gouvernent ces « êtres » : la société dans  son organisation invisible (ici il semblerait que la science soit prédominante), tout ce qui concerne le psychisme et sa complexité, les influences de l'autre et de l'environnement technique sur le soi.

Donc comment connaître ce qui nous influence, ce qui nous manipule secrètement, comment retrouver notre être derrière l'apparence de notre ego dans un contexte psychosocial.

La formulation peut être comprise comme une communication marketing … ou au sens intuitif, résumé d'une réflexion  de la connaissance actuelle d'un domaine qui englobe toute l'entièreté de l'être dans son milieu social.

Tout dépend de la qualité des professeurs : vont-ils parler de ce qu'ils ont appris ou lu, ou vont-ils faire partager, à partir de leur propre expérience, leur connaissance des relations humaines, savoir communiquer les subtilités et les clefs d'un décryptage ardu, dans les limites définies dans le programme.

Comment: N'est-il pas possible que «des génies» s'agit aussi des arts et téchniques comme «génie civil» e.g. [voir IIIA&B du TLFi][1][1]: http://atilf.atilf.fr/dendien/scripts/tlfiv5/visusel.exe?83;s=2891159655;r=4;nat=;sol=0;

Comment: @Micromégas Le lien fourni sur atilf.atilf.fr est perdu après chaque session. Parmi les résultats d'une recherche sur *génie*, j'avais en tête le principe d'un entité abstraite (et souvent inconsciente) : *"Divinité influant sur la destinée d'une personne, d'une collectivité"*. Elle peut s'enraciner en une *"Personne dont l'influence est déterminante, en bien ou en mal, sur une personne, un organisme ou une institution"* ou une institution maîtrisant les techniques artisanales voire artistiques. Mais il y a quelque chose de caché à la vue de l'impétrant, qu'il s'agit de lui révéler